# Crash in react-native android app after installing react-native-splash-screen

Tags: react-native

I am newcomer in react-native.And when I tried to run my android app I can't open my app.I don't know what is wrong in my app.After running this command in terminal `react-native log-android` I encountered with this error.What should I do ?

```
[05:54:59] D | ReactNative ▶︎ ReactInstanceManager.ctor()

[05:54:59] D | ReactNative ▶︎ ReactInstanceManager.createReactContextInBackground()
                           │ ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackgroundInner()
                           │ ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackgroundFromBundleLoader()
                           │ ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackground()
                           └ ReactInstanceManager.runCreateReactContextOnNewThread()

[05:54:59] D | ReactNative ▶︎ ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext()

[05:54:59] D | ReactNative ▶︎ Initializing React Xplat Bridge.

[05:54:59] D | ReactNative ▶︎ Initializing React Xplat Bridge before initializeBridge

[05:54:59] D | ReactNative ▶︎ Initializing React Xplat Bridge after initializeBridge
                           └ CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle()
```

Comment: what version on react-native are you using ? ... if > 0.60 ... Have you tried to run `>npx jetify` in your terminal

Comment: RN 0.61.I tried it but it wasn't helpful

Comment: any update on this? my terminal is telling me it jettifies them every time i try to build